# Does Spring unload unused beans after some time?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

While with Spring Boot application I have noticed that after some time of idleness the application starts to answer requests with some huge delay. Also, when I stop my application my shutdown routines fail because some beans are simply = null. This makes me thinking that Spring has some internal routines which can unload unused beans and recreate them only when needed.

Does Spring have some functionality to shut down unused beans after some period of idleness? Where can I read about it?

Comment: Scoped beans will be GC’d when the scope exits.

Comment: By default, Spring does lazy initialization (https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lazy-init) so your null beans just may never have been referenced.  Also, some application servers may decommission an app that has been idle for a time, but that  behavior could vary if you deployed it to a different container.  (also the scoped beans will be destroyed as mentioned by the previous comment)

Comment: (well, I'm wrong about lazy-loading being on by default -- it has to be enabled; we just usually do in our shop)

Comment: I am using default singleton scope, so thats not my case.